# Multiple curl requests simultaneously

Tags: php, api

For example, on one page I have about 30 different calls like [high_shortcode pair="EURUSD"]..(today's highest price for each pair (EURUSD, GBPUSD .... etc)), which drastically slows down the opening of html and page because the results are waiting for each call until the last and only then opens page.

This is the code I use for one result, the same code I use for other different pair(USDCHF....) on one page.

Can something be done with additional code to reduce load time.

```
function high_shortcode($atts){
        
        ob_start();
        $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'pair' => '',
        ), $atts, 'high_shortcode');


        $pair = $atts['pair'];

        
        $curl = curl_init(get_option( 'api_address' ).'bars/'.$pair.'?timeframe=PERIOD_D1&count=1');

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, get_option( 'api_address' ).'bars/'.$pair.'?timeframe=PERIOD_D1');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

        if ($curl_response === false) {

            $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));

        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $decoded_result = json_decode($curl_response, true);

        echo round($decoded_result['Bars'][0]['High']);
        

        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $content;        
    }
```

i tried the same with multi curl but the result is the same

```
function low_shortcode($atts){
        ob_start();
        
        $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'pair' => '',
            
        ), $atts, 'low_shortcode');

        $pair = $atts['pair'];
         
$urls = array('https://address.com:443/bars/last/'.$pair.'?timeframe=PERIOD_D1&count=1');
$url_count = count($urls);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();        
        
for($i = 0; $i < $url_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$urls[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);


for($i = 0; $i < $url_count; $i++)
{
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
}
        
$decoded_result = json_decode($results, true);

        echo round($decoded_result['Bars'][0]['Low'],$bid_ask_decimal[$pair]);
    
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $content;
        
            
    }
```

{"Request":{"Symbol":"EURUSD","Timeframe":"PERIOD_D1","Count":1},"Bars":[{"Time":1623715200,"Symbol":"EURUSD","Timeframe":"PERIOD_D1","Open":1.21179,"High":1.21259,"Low":1.21138,"Close":1.21250}]}

Comment: Check [curl_multi_init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) for concurrent curl requests. This does mean your current code needs rewriting though

Comment: Why not cache the data? I would assume that pure cURL calls are pretty difficult to use this way, so why not use a library like Guzzle?